# Android Target and Compiled SDK version for Android OREO (API26 or API27)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Below is build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionName "5.3"
..

    }
```

But I am able to run the App on Android OREO ( API version 26 or 27 ) 
How this can be possible?
Do I need to change the target SDK version to 26 or 27?

Comment: Please give explanation before downvoting any question

Comment: Read this to clear your concepts- https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947660/what-should-i-set-for-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-and-targetsdkversion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817578/android-set-targetsdkversion-to-22-to-avoid-runtime-permissions-what-are-the

Comment: `targetSdkVersion` has nothing to do with the Android versions this app will run on. It is the version of SDK which the app will be compiled with

Comment: Even u app will run on the future version of the **Android** ..But u will not get the latest functionalities of new vserion

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you will able to run your app in oreo.
But as your targetSdkVersion is 21,you will be not able to use new features in Oreo or your app might crash if you use a foregroundService.

Comment: Well elaborate.