# Where should I programmatically download new version of my Android App?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-storage

I'm working on an internal app for ~500 users, so I don't want to publish it in the Play Store.

I've built an auto-update mechanism where I check for updates by calling my server and initiate the download using `DownloadManager` and then a `BroadcastReceiver`.

The storage directory where I download the new version of the App is important to me as I don't want to ask my users for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

I've investigated `getFilesDir()`, `getExternalFilesDir()` and `getExternalPublicDir()` but I'm confused what are the pros and cons of each when compared to other, and will there be any blocker that I may face if I choose a particular destination? Any help regarding that will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you don't just use Playstore update mechanism?

Comment: It's an internal application for 500 users only. We don't want to go Play Store path because of internal nature of the application.

Comment: You can use the play store and add people to a list, then they had to join the program and accept it, beta or alpha testing allow you that, you will never need to make public and spare you this distribution mechanism, if that is not enough I would strongly recommend to search for other app store, there are plenty Google Play is just 1 distribution method

Comment: My answer may seem radical and somehow out of the box but if you are not inserting your app to Play Store, then you can set targetSdkVersion below 23 (say 22) and bypass all runtime permission stuffs. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817578/android-set-targetsdkversion-to-22-to-avoid-runtime-permissions-what-are-the

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use getFilesDir() and store the code in your app's private area which is not accessible by other apps, to avoid security risks. The other two options return a directory that is accessible by other apps. You do not need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to write files in the directory returned by getFilesDir().

Comment: Are there any restrictions in terms of available storage space if I go with getFilesDir()?